# simplification help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm unsure on how this simplifies. Could anyone explain how and what technique is used to produce the answer? Any help would be most appreciated.
$$
(n+1)(n+1)!+(n+1)!−1 \\
= (n + 1)!((n + 1) + 1) − 1 \\
= (n + 1)!(n + 2) − 1 
$$

Comment: This is just the distributive law...$AB+B-1=B(A+1)-1$.

Comment: @lulu Why don't you just expand what you have there with a sentence or two and post it as an answer?

Comment: Presumably, you were disturbed by the factor reversal. $(n+1)(n+1)!+(n+1)!=((n+1)+1)(n+1)!=(n+2)(n+1)!$.

Comment: Final answer is $(n+2)! - 1$.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply an application of the distributive law for addition and multiplication.  It looks worse because the terms are themselves a little complicated.  To clarify matters, let $A=(n+1),B=(n+1)!$.  Then your expression is simply $$AB+B-1$$

And this can be rewritten as $$B(A+1)-1$$

That's all that's going on here!

Worth pointing out:  One could take it one step further and remark that $(n+2)(n+1)!=(n+2)!$ thus your expression becomes $$(n+2)!-1$$

Comment: thank you very much for your responce. I understand it now :)